# Uncaught TypeError: socket.to is not a function

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, web-development-server

I want to emit some data to a room in socket.io.

According to the socket.io docs,
In one place (https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Joining-and-leaving) it is said,

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

And in another place (https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) it is said,

```
socket.to('some room').emit('some event', "description");
```

I tried both of these but got the error,

```
uncaught TypeError: io.to is not a function
```

and

```
uncaught TypeError: socket.to is not a function
```

All other socket.io functions i used worked except for this

I included

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

in the head tag of the html file.

In the client side js file, i incuded

```
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/");
```

Also, I used socket.emit and it works the way it is supposed to.

Please tell me what is wrong with this..

Answer (score 3):

If this `Uncaught TypeError` is happening on your client side, that's because `io.to` and `socket.to` are only server-side functions, and **cannot be used on the client side**. In the Client API part of the Socket.IO docs, it doesn't specify `io.to` and `socket.to` as valid API functions. [Here](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) is the client API docs.

And here is a snippet that you can use to emit to `Socket.IO` rooms:

**Server**

```js
//Your code...

io.on("connection", socket => {
  //Don't forget to do this!
  socket.join("some room");
  socket.on("some event", data => {
    //Do socket.to if you want to emit to all clients
    //except sender
    socket.to("some room").emit("some event", data);
    //Do io.to if you want to emit to all clients
    //including sender
    io.to("some room").emit("some event", data);
  });
});
```

**Client**

```js
//Remember to include socket.io.js file!
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
socket.on("some event", data => { /* Whatever you want to do */ });
//To emit "some event"
//This will also emit to all clients in the room because of the way the server
//is set up
socket.emit("some event", "description");
```

#### If you need an explanation...

So what this does is, basically, since you can't emit to rooms on the client side (you can only emit to server), the client emits to the server, and the server emits the event to the room you want to emit to.

Hope this solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Step1: In the client-side js file, changes instead of io.connect("http://localhost:3000/") use given below line,

let io = require('socket.io').listen(server.listener);

Step2: You need to create a connection in (Both Client & serverSide) For the Testing purpose you can use check connection Establish or not Both End use can use Socket.io tester Chrome Extension.(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/socketio-tester/cgmimdpepcncnjgclhnhghdooepibakm?hl=en)

step3: when a socket connection is Established in Both ends then you emit and listen to data Easily.
One thing when you listen to the data then sends Acknowledgement using Callback Function.  I have Received data Successfully.

E.g.`

```
 socket.on('sendMessage',async (chatdata,ack)=>{
         ack(chatdata);
        socket.to(receiverSocketId).emit('receiveMessage',chatdata);

    });
```

`
yours, emitting a message is correct no need to change this one. But make sure and please check it again your socket connection is Establish successfully or not. another Shortcut way you can debug a code line by line you can easily resolve this problem.
I Hope using this approach you can resolve the Error, and it is help For a Future. 
thanks:)